# Can anyone help and tell me why pd.to_numeric is throwing a valueerror?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror, dtype

clean_properties is the dataset, and Average_price is one of the columns.  Its current dtype is object, and I need to convert it to a float. Everything I've looked at online says this is the correct format, but it throws a ValueError.

here is the .head() for the dataframe

```
London_Borough  ID  Month   Average_price
0   City of London  E09000001   1995-01-01  91448.98487
1   Barking & Dagenham  E09000002   1995-01-01  50460.2266
2   Barnet  E09000003   1995-01-01  93284.51832
3   Bexley  E09000004   1995-01-01  64958.09036
4   Brent   E09000005   1995-01-01  71306.56698
```

And this is what I'm trying that is throwing an error

```
clean_properties['Average_price'] = pd.to_numeric(clean_properties['Average_price'])

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "-"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_30444/2671958707.py in <module>
      1 # Try this here
----> 2 clean_properties['Average_price'] = pd.to_numeric(clean_properties['Average_price'])

~\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    181         coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise")
    182         try:
--> 183             values, _ = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
    184                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    185             )

~\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "-" at position 15264
```

Comment: It means the column contains a string `-` which can't be converted to numeric value.

Comment: Do share sample data inputs, to help you

Comment: Any hints on how to fix this? How can I replace the - in the dataframe. I  tried clean_properties.iloc[4:5, 15264:15265]=0, and also clean_properties.at['Average_price', 15264]=0, but neither of those have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your StackTrace ends with: *ValueError: Unable to parse string "-" at position 15264*.

So probably *Average_price* column contains somewhere only "-", meaning
actually "no data".

The indicated position (15264) is probably the row number, indicating the **first**
place where the conversion failed.

One of possible solutions is to convert such inconvertible cases to *NaN*:

```
clean_properties['Average_price'] = pd.to_numeric(
    clean_properties['Average_price'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  It works now and I can continue on in the assignment!!